# laravel elixer gulp ...resources\assets\sass\app.scss <-- Not Found

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5.1, gulp-sass

I tried many times searched all over but not solved i hav updated npm , gulp version

```
 `$ gulp
 [06:53:53] Using gulpfile d:\xampp\htdocs\l5\gulpfile.js
 [06:53:53] Starting 'default'...
 enter code here[06:53:53] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
   - resources\assets\sass\app.scss <-- Not Found`




    Saving To...
       - public\css\app.css

[06:53:53] Finished 'default' after 617 ms
[06:53:53] Finished 'sass' after 626 ms
app.scss is on resources/asset/saas
```

bellow is my gulp file

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass([
        'app.scss',

    ], 'public/assets/css');
});
```

i want to use saas and when it will run it shows above error

if anyone know how to solve plz help
[image: laravel elixer]

Comment: Please check your directory name. It's **saas** not __sass__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elixir not find the file

```
resources\assets\sass\app.scss <-- Not Found`
```

the file is "sass" not "saas"

rename your file "saas" to "sass"

Comment: I'm stupid. Had to see this message to see that I didn't have sass directory :D